# Help Installing SQL Server 2008 Express Edition

Tags: installation, sql-server-2008

Ok I am running Windows 7, 64 bit. I cleaned of SQL server 2005 completely off my system leaving only SQL Compact Edition. I went here http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=01af61e6-2f63-4291-bcad-fd500f6027ff&displaylang=en and installed SQL Server 2008 Express Edition Service Pack 1.

After the install, under my start bar menu all i have for SQL configuration tools are the Configuration Manager, Error and Usage Reporting and the Install Center. I don't have the SQL Managment Studio.

So I went here http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en and downloaded the SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Express but when I try to install it I get a warning says This program has known compatibility issues and that I need to Install SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 1. I thought that is what I installed. So, I tried to continue running the install but I then get an error message that says Invoke or BeginInvoke can not be called on a Form before it is opened...

How can I check if Service pack 1 is installed or not? What should I do?

Also I rebooted my system and checked for Windows Updates and it says that Windows it up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured out the problem. Actually I found the solution on some blog somewhere! The problem is the installer for the ManagementStudio sucks and is not intuitive. When you run the installer it asks you if you want to install a new instance or add features to a current instance. You have to select Install New Instance and NOT Add Features to current instance. This makes no sense to me but I did it and it worked. Thanks to Jack for posting the answer in his blog!